# Este carrusel me está mostrando un item de más. Saben cuál puede ser el error?

Tags: javascript, html

Copié este código de internet y hay un error antes de reiniciar el ciclo.

```js
// Get the DOM elements for the image carousel
const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper"),
carousel = document.querySelector(".carousel"),
images = document.querySelectorAll("img"),
buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
let imageIndex = 1,
intervalId;

// Define function to start automatic image slider
const autoSlide = () => {
  // Start the slideshow by calling slideImage() every 2 seconds
  intervalId = setInterval(() => slideImage(++imageIndex), 2000);
};

// Call autoSlide function on page load
autoSlide();

// A function that updates the carousel display to show the specified image
const slideImage = () => {
  // Calculate the updated image index
  imageIndex = imageIndex === images.length ? 0 : imageIndex < 0 ? images.length - 1 : imageIndex;
  // Update the carousel display to show the specified image
  carousel.style.transform = `translate(-${imageIndex * 100}%)`;
};

// A function that updates the carousel display to show the next or previous image
const updateClick = (e) => {
  // Stop the automatic slideshow
  clearInterval(intervalId);
  // Calculate the updated image index based on the button clicked
  imageIndex += e.target.id === "next" ? 1 : -1;
  slideImage(imageIndex);
  // Restart the automatic slideshow
  autoSlide();
};

// Add event listeners to the navigation buttons
buttons.forEach((button) => button.addEventListener("click", updateClick));

// Add mouseover event listener to wrapper element to stop auto sliding
wrapper.addEventListener("mouseover", () => clearInterval(intervalId));

// Add mouseleave event listener to wrapper element to start auto sliding again
wrapper.addEventListener("mouseleave", autoSlide);
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <i class="button" id="prev">prev</i>
  <div class="image-container">
    <div class="carousel">
      <img src="WhatsApp Image 2023-05-10 at 09.29.22 (1).jpeg" alt="">
      <img src="WhatsApp Image 2023-05-10 at 09.29.22.jpeg" alt="">
      <img src="WhatsApp Image 2023-05-10 at 09.29.24.jpeg" alt="">
      <img src="WhatsApp Image 2023-05-10 at 09.29.22.jpeg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <i class="button" id="next">next</i>
</div>
```

Cambiando el valor del index no funciona, no sé qué otra intentar.

Comment: Tal vez se deba a que estás incrementando el index  `slideImage(++imageIndex)` antes de pasarla como parámetro a la función. Es lo que se me ocurre viendo el código rápidamente. Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código `HTML` necesario para reproducir el caso en un snipet.

Comment: Al parecer ese código es correcto, te falta agregar el CSS. No es la idea que te vayamos solicitando elementos uno a uno. En tu pregunta deberían estar desde el inicio los elementos necesarios y mínimos (sin otras funcionalidades que hacen ruido) para ejecutar tu código y ver el problema. Además el sitio ofrece herramientas para poder ejecutar directamente código html+js+css,